# ListLinePlot with legend

Tags: plotting, legending, map

I have here three example data sets which are plotted with `ListLinePlot`.
Each data sets get its own color and the same is assigned to the labels.

How can I `Map` or simplify the line:

```
Legended[Transpose[{x, y1}], "y1"], Legended[
 Transpose[{x, y2}], "y2"], Legended[Transpose[{x, y3}], "y3"]
```

so that the plot below is obtained?

Example code:

```
SeedRandom["x"];
x = Range[10]*0.3;

SeedRandom["y1"];
y1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];

SeedRandom["y2"];
y2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];

SeedRandom["y3"];
y3 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];

ListLinePlot[{Legended[Transpose[{x, y1}], "y1"], 
  Legended[Transpose[{x, y2}], "y2"], 
  Legended[Transpose[{x, y3}], "y3"]}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "Title"}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: `Legended[Transpose[{x, ToExpression@#}], #] & /@ {"y1", "y2", "y3"}`?

Comment: This one liner works perfect ... Again and again I have the problem that two solutions exist for my question, both great and I can only vote for one ... thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the option `PlotLegends`, e.g.

```
data = Transpose[{x, #}]& /@ {y1, y2, y3};

ListLinePlot[data, 
 PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "Title"}}, ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotLegends -> {"y1", "y2", "y3"}]
```

`Legended` is useful for adding legends to a subset of data sets, but `PlotLegends` is much more convenient. Note, I also removed `Joined -> True` as `ListLinePlot` uses that by default.

Comment: Great ... thanks

Comment: Please excuse me for a short additional question: How can I change the font size of the plot legends? E.g. When I increase to `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}` then the size of the legends is too small.

Comment: This way? `PlotLegends -> (Style[#, 40] & /@ {"y1", "y2", "y3"})]`

Comment: If you want to change the font size for both the plot and the legend, set `LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> size}` in the plots options and the legend will pick it up, too. But, if you only want to set it for the legend, or have a different value for the legend set `PlotLegends -> LineLegend[labels or Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> size}]`.